# a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, directory, virtual

After adding the assebly of System.Data.Entity to my web config I got this error:
It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

I have deleted the obj and bin folders, I removed the line authentication="windows", tried to reopen as some has said it worked, I have checked that there is only 1 web.config within the main folder (Entity Framework - Folder for forms, model, DAL and BLL)...

What other reasons is there that this will happen? I searched everywhere and it's basically the above reasons I found....

This is my web.config if it makes a difference:

```
    <configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="CStringVKB" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=VKB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=websiteservice;Password=websiteservice" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" optimizeCompilations="true" targetFramework="4.0" >
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <!--<authentication mode="Windows">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>-->
     <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>
   <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Basically, the error means that there is a web.config file in one of your subfolders that has a configuration element that it should not have.  Is this you root/only web config file?  If not, could you please post those as well?

Also, it sounds stupid, but I would double check that you're opening the website itself in your IDE (and not mistakenly opening a parent folder)  I have seen people spend a couple hours trying to debug this same error, when all along they weren't in the right directory.

Here is a good explanation on how the web.config hierarchy is set up for ASP that will help you visualize how this works:  http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2010/02/17/163375.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there were two web.config files in my solution. I am using MVC4 and there was another config file under Views and i was making the change in the wrong file. Fixed there helped me.

But you can always change the default redirect/route in the global.asax file.

Answer (score 0):

Chris Noreikis's answer is in fact correct. But missing an important detail. If for whatever reason you open the project/solution in a different VS version than it was originally created VS will attempt to migrate. Occasionally during this migration, VS will create a folder called "backup", or "backup_{#}". Even if you undo the **pending changes** this migration forces, these directories remain.

The presence of these directories are in some cases (like mine) the cause of this error. Removing these directories will eradicate the problem.

My hope is that this saves someone the countless hours I lost on this problem.